# Modify background color with conditional formatting Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to have every other row (`2n + 1`) be the background color I've set it to, but darker. The `2n` cells will remain the color I've set.

I can set the `2n + 1` cells colors with conditional formatting via `=MOD(ROW(),2)=1`, but how can I *overlay* or *modify* the cell color?

Answer (score 2):

Conditional formatting, like regular cell formatting, cannot apply a format relative to another cell.

This behavior could be achieved through a VBA macro.

Comment: How difficult would this be to do? Is it built into Excel?

Comment: It is not trivial.  You would have to learn VBA and write code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have rules for choosing the ambient fill (background) colors of cells,
then you should incorporate those rules into the conditional formatting rules. 
I.e., do all the fill color formatting with conditional formatting. 
If you have assigned colors arbitrarily (or even according to a pattern that you can't describe), then, as Steven says, that's a different kettle of fish.

Comment: Well, I want to do this for 10 different columns, so I'd need to format 10 * colors times...